# url vs sameAs (schema.org)

Tags: url, schema.org

What's the practical difference between using [url](https://schema.org/URL) vs [sameAs](https://schema.org/sameAs) properties in schema.org?

I'm adding microdata information to the big Internet website, contains millions of pages. Using a correct tag is very important. The context may be, for example, the link to the official page on the page describing the County, State or a public Park. It may be also the link to external page with more details about the topic (which may be basically anything in a range from drugs prescriptions to an English grammar).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Note that you are linking to [`schema:URL`](https://schema.org/URL) (which is a datatype) and not to [`schema:url`](https://schema.org/url) (which is the property your questions seems to be about). Schema.org URIs are case-sensitive.]

**For authors:** it often makes sense to think of `url` as the URL that you want to use (typically from your own website), and of `sameAs` as the URL(s) others use for the same thing (typically from external websites).

**For consumers:** it might make sense to use `url` for outputting a link, and for finding more data about the same item from the author’s perspective (e.g., following the link on a teaser page to the full article page), and to use `sameAs` for better understanding what the author is describing in their item.

#### Example

Let’s take [Jamendo](https://www.jamendo.com/) as example, a site about free/libre music.

They have a page about the music group "pornophonique" ([/en/artist/8303/pornophonique](https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique)) and they have various pages that link to this page (e.g., [/en/search?qs=q=pornophonique](https://www.jamendo.com/en/search?qs=q=pornophonique)).

The group also has an official website (http://www.pornophonique.de/) and a Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornophonique).

- On the search result page, Jamendo could simply link to their own URL for that group:

  ```html
  <!-- on <https://www.jamendo.com/en/search?qs=q=pornophonique> -->
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup">
    <a itemprop="url" href="https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique"></a>
  </article>
  ```
- On the dedicated page, they could again specify this `url`, to make clear that it’s the canonical URL for the item:

  ```html
  <!-- on <https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique> -->
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique" />
  </body>
  ```
- And on this same page for the group, Jamendo could use `sameAs` to link to the official website (as the homepage URL typically represents the thing the site is about) and the Wikipedia article:

  ```html
  <!-- on <https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique> -->
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicGroup">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/8303/pornophonique" />

    <section>
      <h1>External links</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.pornophonique.de/">Official website</a></li>
        <li><a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornophonique">Wikipedia article</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </body>
  ```

  (Of course they could do this also on the search result page, if they don’t mind the data repetition/overhead.)
- And just to be sure: On Jamendo’s page about one of their tracks (e.g., https://www.jamendo.com/en/track/81740/sad-robot), Jamendo should **not** use `url` to link to the group’s page or `sameAs` to link to the Wikipedia article, as both URLs do not represent/identify the track. A possible `sameAs` value would be the URL of the page about this track on the group’s official website (http://www.pornophonique.de/download.php?song_id=1).

  ```html
  <!-- on <https://www.jamendo.com/en/track/81740/sad-robot> -->
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.jamendo.com/en/track/81740/sad-robot" />
    <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.pornophonique.de/download.php?song_id=1" />
  </body>
  ```